# getting undefined symbol: key in jni in netbeans

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I am using netbeans installed on linux (x64) machine. I have written a java code it uses the C code as library.

In C code I have declared the variable as extern in header file when I run C code I am getting correct o/p but when I run java code I am getting error as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/pacewisdom-h34/NetBeansProjects/NetbeansJava/desJavaLib/dist/DesJavaLib.so: /home/pacewisdom-h34/NetBeansProjects/NetbeansJava/desJavaLib/dist/DesJavaLib.so: undefined symbol: key
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1938)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1821)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at desjava.DesJava.<clinit>(DesJava.java:10)
/home/pacewisdom-h34/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

`key` is declared as a extern in header file but its giving error.
I saw solution on Stack Overflow itself for 30% similar questions. They mentioned to redefine the variable as intern in the C code. But it keeps on running wont stop.

Answer (score 0):

> `key` is defined as an `extern`

No, it is *declared* as an `extern`, and not *defined* anywhere. It needs to be.